# Internet is very slow on my Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, internet

I am using a Intel Core i5 system with 8 GB RAM and Asus P8B75-Mle Motherboard. I installed both Windows 7 and Windows 8 on my system (dual boot).

In Windows 8, there is a long loading time for web pages (I even tested a Stack Overflow page). I don't know why the system behaves strange in these two situations.

On my Windows Phone I am getting the web pages loaded in minimum time.  I am facing the same issue in both Google Chrome and IE.

Comment: Is your mobile phone going via the wifi? And is it also slow on Windows 7? How are you connecting to the router/modem? Cable, wifi?  If cable, is the cable faulty? If you ping the router from the PC, does it return quick speeds? More detail is needed please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all network drivers are installed and up to date, check your DNS. Maybe after you installed Windows, you forgot to set DNS.

You have to enter your DNS like shown in the below image:

[image]

Comment: While switching DNS servers might be a good idea, google's servers may not always be the fastest - [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/) is a nice little tool for selecting the fastest DNS server in your area

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're PC is up to date with all drivers, most importantly the network drivers. You can go to the [motherboard's manufacturer's](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8B75M_LE/#support_Download) website to see what is available if Windows update does not detect it automatically.